# How to write an event scheduler that run every midnight ? And set a value to 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have written an Event Scheduler in MySQL I don't why it's not working.

I would like to set the reserved = 0. the event should run every midnight at 00:01:00 european time. when the expiration date (exp_date) is less then current date time here is my script.

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS disable_reserved_value_of_prospect 
ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY 
    STARTS '2022-03-30 00:01:00' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
ENABLE 
DO 
    UPDATE prospect 
    SET reserved = 0 
    WHERE exp_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

But my script doesn't work I don't know why ?
Can we use any if condition inside event script?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `event_scheduler` variable enabled ?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html

Comment: Check that Event Scheduler is enabled (execute `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and ensure that the thread for the user `event_scheduler@localhost` is present). Check that the creator have needed permissions for this table updating. Check that system clocks returns correct date and time. Does this query works well while executing in CLI?

Comment: yes it's Enable. I did that globaly

Comment: But my script doesn't work - It's useful to include a debug table which you would insert to right at the start of the event and since the event would now be multi statement you would need a begin..end block and delimiters.You could then see if the event is running as scheduled.  Can we use any if condition inside event script? -Yes see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: Tuer 1
event_scheduler
localhost
NULL
Daemon
407
Waiting for next activation
NULL

Comment: I have 2 event scheduler for the same DB one of them works properly but the second one doesn't work

Comment: *I have 2 event scheduler for the same DB* ??? Maybe you mean event procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` is for one-time event only,so you don't need it in your recurring event. Try modifying the code like below:

```
delimiter //
drop event if exists disable_reserved_value_of_prospect //
CREATE EVENT disable_reserved_value_of_prospect 
ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY 
    STARTS '2022-03-30 00:01:00' DO
BEGIN
    UPDATE prospect 
    SET reserved = 0 
    WHERE exp_date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END //
```

To verify, we can reduce the 1st kick-in time by using `EVERY 1 minute  STARTS now()`. If nothing happens, there is probably something wrong with the UPDATE statement. Substitute it with a TEST statement to insert a line into a test table or something.

Comment: thanks I took your code and  changed the time to eache 5 minutes it works now

Comment: Glad the answer works.

Comment: Single-statement CREATE EVENT does not need in BEGIN-END and DELIMITER.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I guess the old habit can not be undone easily : )